# Error Redirecting URL in flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

**[SOLVED]** : Please read the edit below.

I am trying to build a URL shortener , but I am having error when redirecting user to the longer URL . I have used SQLite for database . 
Here's my redirection code:

```
@app.route('/<short_url>')
def redirect(short_url):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('url.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    result_cur = cursor.execute("SELECT URL FROM WEB_URL WHERE S_URL = ?;" ,(short_url,) )
    try:
        redirect_url = result_cur.fetchone()[0]
        print redirect_url

        conn.close()
        return redirect(redirect_url , code = 200)  
    except Exception as e:
        error  = e 
        return render_template('index.html' , error = error)
```

The `fetchone()[0]` does return the correct long URL , but on clicking the generated short URL I'm getting this error

```
 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

There shouldn't be a `NoneError` because I'm getting a value from the db.

Here's the github link of the project :

https://github.com/PadamSethia/shorty

**EDIT:**

**NOTE**
Turns out , it was a silly mistake. Never name your functions same as that of any inbuilt functions.

Comment: but the error seems to imply that the result of `fetchone()` is actually `None`. have you checked the result?

Comment: please check trace back for error line number

Comment: @Leonard2 Yes , it is fetching the long URL form the db.

Comment: @PadamSethia Could  you print the error stacktrace?

Comment: It is actually throwing an `OperationError` where `e` is  `'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' `

Comment: @Nurzhan it's showing the error on this line :
`redirect_url = result_cur.fetchone()[0]`

Comment: @PadamSethia Then how can you be sure that `result_cur.fetchone()` is not None?

Comment: @Nurzhan because I'm printing the value of redirect_url and it is printing the value correctly . That is why .

Comment: @PadamSethia I don't know then. I can suggest you to change the name of the method - it's `redirect`. And you import `redirect` from flask.

Comment: @Nurzhan I did not get you . Would it help if you look over the whole code , it's barely 60 lines ?

Comment: @Nurzhan Gee , thanks a lot I figured it out  . I named my reroute function as redirect which caused the error . I guess I'm still a noob.

Comment: @PadamSethia I can post it as answer, so that others can know what the reason is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your function `redirect` to something else since you already import `redirect` from flask. Your function name shadows the `redirect` you need.

The same mistake is usually done with `list`. Beginners quite often name lists as `list` which shadows the builtin function `list` and if they try to use it later it creates problems for them.